# Sublassing UIScrollView performSegue on ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, segue

I have a custom UIScrollView class that implements the touchesEnded method. My project has a storyboard, and I am trying to call the performSeguewithIdentifier on the viewcontroller but when I call the method `changePhoto` it gives me the error below. I have verified that my segue is labeled correctly, it is not misspelled. It looks like when I am creating the new instance of the PhotoViewController it doesnt create any of the storyboard and/or the segues. What can I do to call to get the segue to work properly from my UIScrollView?

CustomUIScrollView.m

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        UIView *imageView = [touch view];
        NSInteger tag = imageView.tag;
        NSLog(@"Tag: %d", tag);
        PhotoViewController *vc = [[PhotoViewController alloc]init];
        [vc changePhoto:1];
    }
}
```

PhotoViewController.m

```
-(void)changePhoto:(int)spaceId {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"photoSegue" sender: self];
}
```

Error:

> 2012-10-09 10:28:38.765 Spaces[82945:11303] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with identifier
>   'photoSegue''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing you view controller with this

```
PhotoViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"]
```

Be sure to set the identifier of the according view controller in the interface builder.

Comment: Thanks! Self references the UIScrollView class though so how would it find a storyboard in the UIScrollView Class?

Comment: Error: Property 'storyboard' not found on object of type 'CustomUIScrollView *' :/

Comment: storyboard is a property of `UIVIewController` classes - you have to have/keep a reference to the view controller e.g via a property.

Comment: on the other hand it is not a good design to create a view controller inside a view. Try think about using delegation to inform the view controller of the view that something happened.